# LNK2019 error when using cuda::calcHist() opencv4.1.0+cuda

Tags: opencv

I configure the environment step by step with the tutorial.

This is my Visual Studio 15 project configuration:

1. In VC/C++:
   I add the new built OpenCV library paths to Executable Directories, Include Directories and library Directories.
2. In Linker :
   I have added all the libs:

   opencv_aruco410d.lib
   opencv_bgsegm410d.lib
   opencv_bioinspired410d.lib
   opencv_calib3d410d.lib
   opencv_ccalib410d.lib
   opencv_core410d.lib
   opencv_cudaarithm410d.lib
   opencv_cudabgsegm410d.lib
   opencv_cudacodec410d.lib
   opencv_cudafeatures2d410d.lib
   opencv_cudafilters410d.lib
   opencv_cudastereo410d.lib
   opencv_cudawarping410d.lib
   opencv_cudev410d.lib
   opencv_datasets410d.lib
   opencv_dnn410d.lib
   opencv_dnn_objdetect410d.lib
   opencv_dpm410d.lib
   opencv_features2d410d.lib
   opencv_flann410d.lib
   opencv_fuzzy410d.lib
   opencv_gapi410d.lib
   opencv_hfs410d.lib
   opencv_highgui410d.lib
   opencv_imgcodecs410d.lib
   opencv_imgproc410d.lib
   opencv_img_hash410d.lib
   opencv_line_descriptor410d.lib
   opencv_ml410d.lib
   opencv_objdetect410d.lib
   opencv_optflow410d.lib
   opencv_phase_unwrapping410d.lib
   opencv_plot410d.lib
   opencv_quality410d.lib
   opencv_reg410d.lib
   opencv_rgbd410d.lib
   opencv_saliency410d.lib
   opencv_shape410d.lib
   opencv_stereo410d.lib
   opencv_structured_light410d.lib
   opencv_surface_matching410d.lib
   opencv_text410d.lib
   opencv_tracking410d.lib
   opencv_video410d.lib
   opencv_videoio410d.lib
   opencv_xfeatures2d410d.lib
   opencv_ximgproc410d.lib
   opencv_xobjdetect410d.lib
   cudart.lib
   cufft.lib
   kernel32.lib
   user32.lib
   gdi32.lib
   winspool.lib
   comdlg32.lib
   advapi32.lib
   shell32.lib
   ole32.lib
   oleaut32.lib
   uuid.lib
   odbc32.lib
   odbccp32.lib

I want to use cuda::calchist() and histrange in cudaimgproc. No error is showed in the IDE but when compiling it shows linker error "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol". I've tried all the methods from other posts with this topic but couldn't find the solution.

This is error message:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::cuda::calcHist(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray const &,class cv::cuda::Stream &)" (?calcHist@cuda@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@2@AEBV_OutputArray@42@AEAVStream@12@@Z) referenced in function main  cuda_moduletest C:\Users\50965\Desktop\cuda_Moduletest\cuda_datatranstest\Testopencv.cu.obj 1   1
```

I have added the .dll library locations to the Environment Variables / System Variables PATH.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector> 
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/cudafilters.hpp>
#include<opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>

size_t Fsize = sizeof(float);

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{

    float *h_a = (float*)malloc(Fsize * 200);
    float *h_b = (float*)malloc(Fsize * 200);
    float *h_c = (float*)malloc(Fsize * 400);
    float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_a, Fsize * 200));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_b, Fsize * 200));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_c, Fsize * 400));

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        h_a[i] = rand() % 255;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        h_b[i] = 1;
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, Fsize * 200, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, Fsize * 200, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cudaMemcpy(d_c, h_a, Fsize * 200, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy((d_c + 200), h_b, Fsize * 200, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaMemcpy(h_c, d_c, Fsize * 400, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("Rawdata:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
            printf("%f \t", h_c[j + i * 200]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    try {
        cv::cuda::GpuMat dst, src,hist;
        cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("C://Users//50965//Desktop//sy//5.BMP");
        src.upload(src_host);
        cv::cuda::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::cuda::equalizeHist(dst,hist);
        cv::Mat result_host;
        dst.download(result_host);
        cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception&ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error:" << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I can get correct output if I delete `cv::cuda::equalizeHist(dst,hist);`, so I don't know what is the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see `opencv_cudaimgprocXXX.lib` in your list of libraries.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651827/opencv-cudaimgproc-errors).  Your question appears to be a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Robert Crovella Thanks a lot. I just printed out and added all libs from D:\opencv\source_built\install\x64\vc14\lib. So I found that there is no opencv_cudaimgprocXXX.lib in my built library, But I can find this cudaimgproc.hpp in my external dependencies?

Comment: @Robert Crovella What should I do? Do I need to rebuild the opencv library? Thanks your help.

Comment: I would say if you don't have that library, then you would probably need to build it.  That seems like a different question, and probably there are many resources to explain how to build OpenCV including with GPU. I won't be able to give you detailed instructions, myself.

Comment: I know how to build Opencv with GPU..But it will cost too much time so I wonder if I can only rebuild the missing lib, thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: are you sure that the library is not already in the OpenCV lib folder? Maybe you just forgot to add it to the linker

Comment: @Miki I have checked that folder. Perhaps something went wrong when I built OpenCV and I didn’t notice. Thanks, I am building it again now ..